# How to perform Ansible task if given directory is not empty?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to move logs to backup directory (using `shell` module, `mv` command).

`mv` command fails if there are no files to move.
By default, it causes whole Ansible play to fail.
I can proceed with play, even if task fails (`ignore_errors: yes`)

I am not satisfied with this solution, because it produces error message

> TASK [move files to backup directory]
>   ****************************************** fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! =...?No such file or directory", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines":
>   [], "warnings": []} ...ignoring

How to check if directory is empty in Ansible,  and if empty jus skip task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use find module in ansible 2.0 to find files with `.log` extension in directory then execute move if files is found

```
- find: paths=DIRECTORY file_type=directory patterns="*.log"
  register: dir_files

- shell: mv *.log /tmp
  when: dir_files.matched|int != 0
```

Comment: great, thanks! A question: is this a good idea to add 'changed_when: false' to 'find' task? This command is always running, never changing anything. 
I usually add changed_when: false to such pure tests, without side effects. That way, handlers are not called and play recap looks better (I have changed=0, unless something is really changed).

Comment: @BartoszBilicki - changed is always set to false since the find module does not change anything:
{
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 6,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [],
        "matched": 0,
        "msg": ""
    }

Answer (score 1):

There is accepted answer that uses `find` module.

Another option (less readable and more verbose) is to use native Linux commands- `test` result of `ls` command

```
- name: "backup logs"
  shell: test "$(ls /var/logs/)"
  register: logsPresent
  changed_when: false

- name: "move files to backup directory"
  when: "logsPresent.rc != 0"
  shell: "mv /var/logs/ /backup/logs"
```

Comment: This moves the whole source directory, not the files inside!